# emplace_back with initializer list

Tags: c++, initializer-list, emplace

I'm trying to run the following code on VS2022:

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec;
    //auto list = (std::initializer_list<int>){ 5, 6 };
    vec.emplace_back((std::initializer_list<int>) { 5, 6 });
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives me an error:

> Error C4576   a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax

and

> expected an expression.

According to other answers this should work but it's not the case for me on VS2022, not even the commented line works. I tried compiling it using g++ and it was successful. Any ideas why?

Comment: You are doing a "C" style cast of an integer array. `vec.emplace_back(std::initializer_list{5, 6});` should work. Even though it looks strange to me in this very minimal example (don't get me wrong a MRE is good)

Answer (score 4):

The C-style cast has the form `(type)expression`, and `{...}` isn't an expression (it doesn't have a type, and so on).

Probably the reason why this syntax isn't allowed is that C has something *called compound literals* with syntax `(type){...}`, with wildly different behavior compared to a cast, so reusing the same syntax in C++ for a different thing is probably a bad idea.

You want a functional cast, in the form `type{...}`. So, `std::initializer_list<int>{5, 6}`.

But if I was you, I'd use `.push_back({5, 6})`. Yes, this uses one extra move, but the syntax is cleaner.

Comment: Does this construct an initializer_list then copies it into vec? if so, this beats the purpose of using emplace_back.

Comment: @YousefIrshaid What do you mean? The individual elements of the list are copied into the vector (not moved due to the poor design of `initializer_list`, but for an `int` copying and moving is the same thing), but it's the same thing that happens when you do `std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};`.

Comment: I know that when emplacing back a user defined type, I need to pass the constructor arguments to the method so that the object is constructed directly into the vector without moves or copies. I want to achieve the same functionality with vector, what do you suggest ?

Comment: @YousefIrshaid `.emplace_back(std::initializer_list<int>{1,2,3})` is optimal. `.push_back({1,2,3})` is less optimal due to one extra move.